# SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery throws Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a simple method to execute SQL NON-QUERY statement. This works fine without any issue but when there is load or 20 thread simultaneously calling this method than sometime I get "Collection was modified; enumeration operation might no execute". Surprisingly I do not have any enumeration operation in this method.

Method:

```
OpenConnection();
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, Connection))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    if (QueryParam.Count() > 0)
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(QueryParam.ToArray());

    SqlParameter scopeParam = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 0);
    scopeParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    uKey = (int)cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value;
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
}
CloseConnection()
return uKey;
```

Exception:

```
Exception Found: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.

Full Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(SqlCommand cmd, _SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Just to mention I am using .Net 4.0 and SQL Server.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `OpenConnection()`  \ `CloseConnection()` - don't do this. Create connection when you need it, open, dispose when done. So in this case, create it right before creating command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code shown *by itself* should be fine; the symptoms here suggest that another thread is touching the same `Connection` instance at the same time, so: don't do that. Connections are not thread-safe. The key give-aways here are shown in bold:

> This works **fine without any issue** [presumably meaning by itself] but **when there is load** or 20 thread simultaneously calling this method than **sometime** I get "Collection was modified; enumeration operation might no execute".

Something that happens only sometimes and only when under concurrent load: is usually concurrency. Recommendation: scope the connection - either per thread, or even per method, i.e.

```cs
using (var conn = CreateOpenConnection())
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLQuery, conn))
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Only thing that is bothering me is that the exception is coming from System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery and not from the Open/Close connection.

Comment: @RanjanKumar if you've got two threads mutating the internal state, *all bets are off* - you're in thoroughly undefined territory. Literally anything could happen. It is entirely expected (to me) that it explodes in the internals; it isn't just opening and closing the connection that change the internal state